# asp.net Response.Write

Tags: asp.net

```
  Response.Write("<script>alert('Konaklama Başarıyla Eklendi')</script>");
  string url = "NewAccommodation.aspx?mID=" + mID;
  Response.Redirect(url);
```

Hi, on the above code, it does not show the alert box because of the code lines after it. How to fix that?

Comment: You will have to put the message box on the NewAccommodation.aspx page... once you have redirected, nothing else is going to happen on the original page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working on your exceedingly limited code, you have two options as I see it...

Redirect to `NewAccommodation.aspx` and then write the "alert" script from there

Or send the following....

```
Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>")
Response.Write("alert('Konaklama Başarıyla Eklendi');")
Response.Write("document.location.href='NewAccommodation.aspx?mID=" + mID.ToString() + "';")
Response.Write("</script>")
```

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help. Knowing the life cycle of the communication between the server and the client (as well as exactly what is going to happen on each side) is key to effective ASP.NET programming

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try this

```
  string url = "NewAccommodation.aspx?mID=" + mID;
  Response.Redirect(url);
```

And put this on NewAccommodation.aspx `page_load`

```
if(!IsPostBack)
    Response.Write("<script>alert('Konaklama Başarıyla Eklendi')</script>");
```

Comment: Except that if he does it like this he will see the alert every time the page is loaded even if the user did not come with this particular redirect.

Comment: `string url = "NewAccommodation.aspx?mID=" + mID + "&showmessage=1`

Answer (score 1):

`Response.Redirect` sends a header to the browser that causes it to navigate to another URL. As its a header, its in the first part of the response so anything that follows it that isn't also header (like your output) is never handled by the browser.

Insted you can;

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('Konaklama Başarıyla Eklendi'); location.href='" + url  + "'</script>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options

1. Redirect to an URL that knows how to display the alert. You may include an argument in the query string but don't include the script itself in the querystring because it is a security risk.
2. Do a client side redirect via script after the alert by setting window.location.href property.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

Response.Write("alert('Konaklama Başarıyla Eklendi'); window.location.href='NewAccommodation.aspx?mID=" + mID +"'");

Happy coding!!!