# giving an alert after a successful sign up in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to give an alert after person sign up successfully. And then I redirect it to index page I tried something like that

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + "Login is successful!" + "');", true);
Response.Redirect("index.html");
```

But alert cannot be seen.

Comment: Replication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081533/asp-net-response-write/11081679

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a cookie. On successful login add a cookie in response, containing a greeting text, and on the landing page - check with javascript if the cookie exists, and if yes - show the alert, and delete the cookie. This way you can personalize the alert message with user's name for instance.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work -- you're registering a startup script to the current page, but then redirecting to a different page.  So the page with your script never gets sent back to the client.

You could try one of two approaches instead:

1. Register the script after the redirect (of course the redirect target would have to be an *aspx* file, not *html* for this to work).
2. Add another line to the startup script that performs the redirect on the client side.  (ie, using *window.location = index.html* after the alert)